# Jetty ALPN/NPN Exception while connecting to BigTable from Spark, scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

Facing Issues while trying to connect to the BigTable from Spark 
Below is the error I am facing while executing the connection

```
    INFO grpc.BigtableSession: Bigtable options: BigtableOptions{dataHost=bigtable.googleapis.com, tableAdminHost=bigtableadmin.googleapis.com, instanceAdminHost=bigtableadmin.googleapis.com, projectId=ProjectID, instanceId=InstanceForBigTable, userAgent=hbase-1.2.5, credentialType=DefaultCredentials, port=443, dataChannelCount=20, retryOptions=RetryOptions{retriesEnabled=true, allowRetriesWithoutTimestamp=false, statusToRetryOn=[UNAVAILABLE, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, UNAUTHENTICATED, INTERNAL, ABORTED], initialBackoffMillis=5, maxElapsedBackoffMillis=60000, backoffMultiplier=2.0, streamingBufferSize=60, readPartialRowTimeoutMillis=60000, maxScanTimeoutRetries=3}, bulkOptions=BulkOptions{asyncMutatorCount=2, useBulkApi=true, bulkMaxKeyCount=25, bulkMaxRequestSize=1048576, autoflushMs=0, maxInflightRpcs=1000, maxMemory=715862835, enableBulkMutationThrottling=false, bulkMutationRpcTargetMs=100}, callOptionsConfig=CallOptionsConfig{useTimeout=false, shortRpcTimeoutMs=60000, longRpcTimeoutMs=600000}, usePlaintextNegotiation=false}.

Exception in thread "BigtableSession-startup-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:159)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:136)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:124)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:94)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.createSslContext(BigtableSession.java:132)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.access$000(BigtableSession.java:84)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession$2.run(BigtableSession.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code which I am trying to create connection

```
val tableDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> hbaseReadSchema))
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").load()
```

Can Anyone provide reasons for the above-mentioned error?

Comment: Please remove the PII from the first line.  Also, we have a working example of SparkSQL via hortornworks-shc here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a dependency issue.

Using `bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop:1.0.0-pre3` should fix most of the possible dependency pitfalls. It shades all of the `bigtable` dependencies and is designed to work well with `hadoop` environments.

As Solomon pointed out in his comment, please model your dependencies after the example on github.